# How to increment HTML h4 tag in AJAX call? I am getting h41, h42 values when I debug

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script>
   var pageUrl = "http://localhost:12152/Product.aspx";
 window.onload = function () {
    var ncount = 0;
        ncount++;
   $("#callproceed").click(function () {
      alert("working");
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                    url: pageUrl + '/AddProceed',
                data: '{subPoints:' +    parseInt($("#h4+ncount").html()) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
               success: function (response) {
              alert(response.d);
      } ,
             failure: function (response) {
                 alert(response.d);
          }
      });
   });
 }; 
 </script>
```

I am making an AJAX call to fetch all dynamic data in HTML tag but only I am getting 1 value.

Comment: `'#h4+ncount'` is not a math/concatenation operation. it's a string with the letters `n`, `c`, `o`, etc...

Comment: Try `parseInt($("#h4" + ncount).html()`?

Comment: but still not working. giving only only h41 value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to store the count inside #h4? Try this:

```
$("#h4").html(ncount++)
```

Comment: this is the tag where i am adding the count in js.script file.

Comment: @ace.riyaz Please edit your initial question and add a snippet of html that contains the `<h4>` tags you are trying to parse.